# Sharepoint REST API

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint

Can anybody tell me where can I see a documentation for the sharepoint rest api ? I would like to see documentation like swagger has e.g. endpoints + dto objects. I need to make an integration with sharepoint to have CRUD functional for files. On [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index) I see an articls that describe how to use it, but can`t find concrete list with endpoints and data tansfer objects.

Comment: I suggest you refer to this document, it contains some examples of CRUD operations with SharePoint using the REST API： https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the official Microsoft documentation : [SharePoint REST service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom),

Please read all the part in the left navigation :
[image]

**Bonus** : Also, if you are a beginner and you want to start with SP API, I recommend you to use SP Insider extention, it is a free SharePoint Discovery tool for Developers. It allows you to explore the endpoint in an intuitive way and build your Query easily.

Cordially.

Comment: Thank you for the extention, it must be useful. Bad, that SharePoint don`t have a Swagger.

Comment: SP Insider will save you a lot of time, if my answer helped you thanks for marking it as an answer ♥